# RequireJS: how to load js from multiple domains?

Tags: requirejs

I have scripts under two domains:

```
main.mydomain.com
- /scripts/
    - entry.js
    - userManager.js


user.mydomain.com
- /scripts/
    - user.js
    - admin/
        - superUser.js
```

The entry.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/scripts/',
    paths: {
        'userManager': 'userManager.js',
        'user': 'http://user.mydomain.com/scripts/user'
    },
    deps: ['userManager']
});
```

When I deploy them all under one domain, everything works fine. But when they are under the two domains, the /admin/superUser.js is not loaded.

The reason I see is: the browser tries to load `/admin/superUser.js` from `main.mydomain.com`, but the js is supposed to be load from `user.mydomain.com`.

The `user.js` looks like below

```
define(['./admin/superUser'], function(superUser) {
 ....
})
```

How I can config requirejs to make the file load from the second domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work the way you are doing it because relative paths in dependencies are interpreted relative to the *module name*, not to the *module path*.

You load `http://user.mydomain.com/scripts/user.js` as `user`. So when RequireJS interprets `./admin/superUser` it takes the directory part of the module name `user`, which is empty and adds `admin/superUser` to it, so you get the module name `admin/superUser` which is not defined in `paths` and so RequireJS constructs a path for it by tacking `baseUrl` to it and adding `.js` at the end.

One way to do it that should work is to access the hierarchy of modules at `http://user.mydomain.com/scripts` under a directory in your module name space, so you could put this in your paths *instead* of the path you have for `user` now:

```
'userlib': 'http://user.mydomain.com/scripts'
```

And then replace requests of the module `user` to requests of `userlib/user`. So the `user.js` will now be accessed under the module name `userlib/user`. When this module requests `./admin/superUser` the directory part of the module name is `userlib` and the final module name for the request is `userlib/admin/superUser`. The entire module name is not defined in `paths` but the prefix `userlib` is defined so RequireJS uses the prefix to build a final URL which is `http://user.mydomain.com/scripts/admin/superUser.js`.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time!